# nodejs: force callback execution if method hangs

Tags: node.js, callback

i have a situation where my asynchronus nodejs method from a third party library is taking too long. i want to set a timeout limit on this call and if it does not return within that timeout, i want a callback to happen with default(empty) values.

current code

```
wrapperfunct(data, function(value, err) {
  //do everything with value or err
})


wrapperfunc(data, callback) {
      thirdpartylib.getData(input, callback)
    }
```

i am noticing that getData sometimes hangs, that prevents the callback from happening. i want a behavior than if getData does not call the callback method in specified time, i call callback with default values, say (null, null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own timeout like this:

```
wrapperfunc(obj, timeout, data, callback) {
   var done = false;
   var timer = setTimeout(function() {
       done = true;
       // callback with both values null to signify a timeout
       callback(null, null);
   }, timeout);
   obj.thirdpartylib.getData(input, function(err, data) {
       if (!done) {
           clearTimeout(timer);
           done = true;
           callback(err, data);
       }
   })
}
```

Note: The value of `this` in your proposed function was probably not correct so I substituted `obj`.  You will either have to pass that value in or you will have to use some variable that is within scope for that.

Comment: thanks, would not i also need a similar check for done within setTimeout(), like setTimeout(fucntion() { if(!done) { done= true, callback(null,null);}, timeout); :)

Comment: @jsfriend00 wouldn't the callback within `setTimeout` be called even when third-party-library callback is completed in time?

Comment: @blazesahlzen - see the clearTimeout that makes it so the timeout is not fired in that case.

Comment: Oh yes, I seem to have missed that.

Comment: @konquestor - see the `clearTimeout()` that stops the timer from firing if the third party call is successful.  So, it can never fire except when the third party call has not yet completed.

Comment: @konquestor - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.